# Unable to make html5 with css work with all browsers

Tags: html

I have a page that I am trying to write. I want a header, footer three columns that are 20% 60% 20%.  I am trying to use html5.  This code works with firefox but IE the div tag is way at the bottom. andriod the left over laps, chrome shows the div at the bottom.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The example is [**here**](http://rockymountaintrials.org/HTMLPage1.html).

```
 <html>
    <header>...</header>
    <section>
    <nav>buttons below the header not to exceed 20% align left
    </nav>
    <div>
    </div>
    <style>
    header {
    background-color:#744626;
    color:#41200b;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    height:186px;
   }
    nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#fbf2dc;
    height:1947px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    }
    section {
    width:600px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fbf2dc;
    height:2000px;
    vertical-align:top;
    }
    aside{
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#fbf2dc;
    height:2000px;
    }
    footer {
    background-color:#fbf2dc;
    color:#41200b;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    }
    body {
    background-color:#fbf2dc;
    color:#41200b;
    }
    img {
    display: block
    }
    .Normal-C17
    {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; font-weight:700; 
    font-size:15.0px; line-height:30px; color:#0000ff; 
    text-align:center;
    }
    table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #744626;
    }
    </style>
    </section>
    <aside>s</aside>
    <footer>be centered and be the bottom 10% of page</footer>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try out Fluid Layout feature. Link below CSS files which are highly customizable. It is having a good feature in which the web page can adjust in mobile, tablet or a desktop i.e. responsive.

Try them out and customize, I just uploaded them. (If you have not used fluid feature in Adobe Dreamweaver before.)

link to styles.css file :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r5pb2uvexf0nw9/styles.css?dl=0

link to boilerplate.css file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzy6w848s0ndedi/boilerplate.css?dl=0

I hope above steps helps you